# jQuery .animate Sliding Panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a grid that uses the following code to randomly apply an active "highlight" class to one of the child li elements

```
 //add class "highlight" to random panel

var elements = $('ul#sliding_panels li');
$ (elements.get (
  Math.round (elements.length*Math.random ()-0.5)
)).addClass ('highlight');
```

Basically, the li element with the .highlight class will be 2x the size of the other panels.

The tricky part is that I'm looking to remove this .highlight class and attach it to a new li element when it is highlighted.

I thought this code would do the trick but it's not returning anything when I hover .highlight (or doing anything else for that matter!)

**EDIT: I've added the code to jsfiddle.net for people to see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/dxzqv/2/**

```
    <script>

//add class "highlight" to random panel
        $(document).ready(function(){         

            var elements = $('ul#sliding_grid li');
            $ (elements.get (
              Math.round (elements.length*Math.random ()-0.5)
            )).addClass ('highlight');        

//animation on hover            

            $('#sliding_grid li').hover(function() {
              $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }, function() {
              $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            });

            $(".highlight").hover(
                function(){$(this).animate({width: 400px, height:400px}, 1000);},        
                function(){$(this).animate({width: 200px, height:200px}, 1000);}
            );        

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Is this run in a `$(document).ready(function(){`?  You need to wait for the DOM to load.

Comment: Good question.  No it's not - I confess javascript ignorance!  I've added this code to jsfiddle.net so people can see it much more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/dxzqv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dxzqv/3/

How's that?

Not sure if that is the effect you were going for, stuff is happening.

Going to fork and tweak some more.

```
//add class "highlight" to random panel
        $(document).ready(function(){         

            var elements = $('ul#sliding_grid li');
            $ (elements.get (
              Math.round (elements.length*Math.random ()-0.5)
            )).addClass ('highlight');        

//animation on hover            

            $('#sliding_grid li').hover(function() {
              $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }, function() {
              //$(this).removeClass('highlight');
            });

            $(".highlight").live("hover", function(){
                $(this).animate({"width": "400px", "height":"400px"}, 1000);       

            });   

            $(".highlight").live("mouseout", function(){
                $(this).animate({"width": "200px", "height":"200px"}, 1000, function(){
                 $(this).removeClass('highlight');   
                });        

            });        

        });
```

Comment: Beautiful!  The only problem is it's giving alot of delayed chaining.  Where the boxes are bouncing alot after mouseOut...any idea how to correct that / stabilize the animation?

Comment: On second thought, I should use HoverIntent for that, no need to reinvent the wheel!  The problem is that they are "bouncing" right now because they are set to immediately animate and then shrink again, I just need them to shrink again on mouseOut.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I will need to absolute position them to prevent all the stacking nonesense but your code is perfect. THANK YOU!

Comment: P.S. - jsfiddle.net probably doesn't store the code forever - if you want others to vote up your code you should probably copy and paste the code from jsfidle.net into your answer here!